# Disable indentation for Lambda Expressions/Anonymous Classes in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

The following image pretty much illustrates the whole issue:
[image: When pressing ENTER IntelliJ IDEA indents the closing brace relative to the lambda expression, while it should go relative to the parent expression's braces.]

I have tried using `// formatter:off` with the appropriate settings, but to no avail. I have also tried looking for indentation rules for lambda expressions/anonymous classes, but I couldn't find those.

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: The default setting for IDEA 14 is exactly what you see in the "what I would like to see". I think you have some non-standard indentation setting active. :'(

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young If so, then were would one change the necessary settings to default?

Answer (score 6):

You need to close the outmost parenthesis right next to the closing bracket for the anonymous class to get the desired indentation.

Instead of:

```
itemClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                              }
                            }
);
```

Remove the line/space between the last } and ); and you get:

```
itemClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the option "Use indents relative to expression start" in
`Editor > Code Style > Java`

[image: Use indents relative to expression start]

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me was setting
`Editor > Code Style > Java > Continuation indent` to a lower value.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea 14.1.1

Select checkbox

"File" [menu]/"Settings"/"Code Style"/"Enable formatter markers in comment"

(see field "Formatter off" and field value, for me it is "@formatter:off")

Then use `// @formatter:off` in your code.

Example:

```
// @formatter:off
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Path>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Path> subscriber) {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream  = Files.newDirectoryStream(rootDir, filePattern)) {
            for (Path path : stream) subscriber.onNext(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was disabling the EditorConfig support:

File/Settings/Editor/Code Style: uncheck Enable EditorConfig support.

Answer (score 0):

The new object is a call argument. Disable 'align when multiline' for 'method call arguments' will do the none indented formatting. This does also work for lambdas.

[image]